# Apache-NiFi putSQS processor fails - gives MessageGroupId parameter not found in the request

Tags: apache-nifi

My flowfile just before sending to NiFi putSQS processor is
{"messageGroupId": "867844001232878", "seq_no" : 1, "lat" : 18.5020556, "long" : 73.8351984}
I added "messageGroupId" as attribute still it gives me gives MessageGroupId parameter not found in the request. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JaYpp.png)

Answer (score 1):

I connected over slack channel for NiFi and response I got is
The PutSQS processor doesn’t support FIFO - someone added support through a patch on jira, but it hasn’t been merged into NiFi yet :disappointed:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-4540